# Random walk on white faces of a soccerball

Tags: probability

Suppose you do a random walk on the 20 white (hexagonal) faces of a soccer-ball.

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Soccerball.svg

At each time step you go back to and adjacent white face, selecting the adjacent faces at random with equal probability.

What is the expected number of steps until you return to the original position?

I believe the answer is 20, the same as the number of white faces.

A harmonic function on a finite graph must be constant or have at least two poles, so the only stationary distribution gives all the faces equal probability of 1/20.  The expected return time is thus 1/(1/20).

Comment: Perhaps not everyone knows the tiling associated with soccer balls, might be a good idea to describe it.  Ideally, since you only care about the white hexagons, describe the associated graph.

Comment: Sketch:  draw the graph associated with the hexagons  (it's got $20$ vertices, and an edge between two means that the two hexagons share a border).  Let $E_i$ be the expected number of moves given that you start on $i$.  Then, if hexagon $i$ borders hexagons $j,k,l$ we have $E_i=1+\frac {E_j+E_k+E_l}3$ where, to abuse notation a bit, $E_*$ on the right is now $0$ if $*$ is the special hexagon.  Easy to solve that system (at least with a machine).

Comment: Note:  the symmetries greatly speed the computation.  For instance, the three hexagons bordering $*$ all have the same expectation, so you don't need anything like $20$ separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment (so please don't downvote)... but includes figures.

The soccer ball is a truncated icosahedron:

[image]

With this net (without the white/black distinction).

[image]

Here is its graph of edges:

[image]

---

In *Mathematica*:

```
Graphics3D[PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Faces", "Polygon"]]

PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "Net"]

GraphData["TruncatedIcosahedralGraph"]
```

Comment: The graph associated with the random walk described in the question is actually that of a regular dodecahedron.